# I am living in UK and using money earned outside of UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, savings

I am currently a UK resident on spouse visa.
I still have got my home country's bank account.
I also have debit card linked to the account in my home country bank account.
Can I use/spend this money in UK.
Do I need to declare this in any tax form? or pay any taxes?

Comment: If you are a resident of the UK for tax purposes, then the only money you would need to declare for tax purposes is any interest, dividends, or other income you receive from the money (savings) you have in your home country.

Comment: thanks. well, do I have to pay tax for just simply use? for instance just withdwoing money from that bank account. and if so, how? and what should I do?

Comment: No, the tax authorities are not (in general) interested in how you spend your money.

Comment: and I get gift money from my parenrs per months to that same account, and I get around £10 saving interesrs in a year, but do I need to do anything for it too? I've heard gift money isn't taxed in UK, and I can get up£16,000 interests without paying tax?

Comment: The UK personal tax allowance is currently 11,000, not 16,000.  Gift money is not subject to tax.  Any income above 11,000 is taxable.  If you have paid tax in your home country on the interest income, then you will get a tax credit from the UK tax office, assuming there is a tax treaty between the UK and your home country.  This means you will not be double taxed.  However, if your home country tax rates are lower than those in the UK, then you will be required to the difference between the two rates on any interest income over the 11,000 allowance.

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous one? http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/73356/money-from-my-parents-from-abroad-to-my-bank-account-in-uk

Comment: @NickR the £16K comes from my answer to the previous question I just linked: there's a new savings exemption, and if you have <£11K earned income, you can make up to £16K total before you pay any tax.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Thanks for the update.  I'm not sure if such a provision was in place when I was living in London (I left 4 years ago), but it makes sense to offer such an advantage to people on low income.